# How to deserialize "<MyType><StartDate>01/01/2000</StartDate></MyType>"

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-deserialization

How to deserialize "<MyType><StartDate>01/01/2000</StartDate></MyType>"

below is the MyType definition

```
[Serializable]
public class MyType
{
    DateTime _StartDate;
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        set
        {
            _StartDate = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _StartDate;
        }
    }
}
```

Got the following error while deserializing

> {"The string '01/01/2000' is not a
>   valid AllXsd value."}
>       [System.FormatException]: {"The string '01/01/2000' is not a valid
>   AllXsd value."}
>       Data: {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}
>       HelpLink: null
>       InnerException: null
>       Message: "The string '01/01/2000' is not a valid AllXsd value."
>       Source: "System.Xml"
>       StackTrace: "   at System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTime..ctor(String
>   text, XsdDateTimeFlags kinds)\r\n   at
>   System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime(String
>   s, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode
>   dateTimeOption)\r\n   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlCustomFormatter.ToDateTime(String
>   value)\r\n   at
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ToDateTime(String
>   value)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMyType.Read2_MyType(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderMyType.Read3_MyType()"
>       TargetSite: {Void .ctor(System.String,
>   System.Xml.Schema.XsdDateTimeFlags)}

Answer (score 2):

If you really can't control the input XML but still have to parse it(despite being improper), something like this is what I've done in the past.

```
[Serializable]
public class MyType
{
    DateTime _StartDate;
    public string StartDate
    {
        set
        {
            _StartDate = DateTime.Parse(value);
        }
        get
        {
            return _StartDate.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @awlawl: So, no way to deserialize DateTime type?

Answer (score 1):

Probably DateTime deserializer expects a different format to the one you have there.

The format I use looks like this:

```
2010-01-20T13:40
```

(This is for a UTC DateTime, you can also have timezones on the end of the string)

I use this format to send to with [DataMember] properties and the DataContractSerializer deals with it fine, so I guess it will work with Xml Serialization as well.

There's a thread about the error you are getting [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/4af6463f-1634-4660-b403-1c29bf478120) that looks like it might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In short I think you don't. Your problem is that that the `XmlSerializer` tries to parse the `01/01/2000` into a `DateTime` value, but `01/01/2000` is not a [valid XML date](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp).

How is the XML string created? Do you have control over that code? If so, use the [`XmlConvert.ToString(DateTime)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zds88xsz.aspx) method to get a string that conforms to the standard.

Comment: @Fredrik: No, I don't have control over XML string formation. It is sent from client. In my side I am trying to Deserialize the given xml string.